# Is there a way to load an HDR image from a file input in JS?

Tags: javascript, file, three.js

I am working on a web editor for glTF scenes, one feature is testing HDR environment maps.

I'm using a file input, which does accept `.hdr` files –

```
<input type="file" accept=".jpg,.png,.hdr">
```

However, when accessing the `File`, the [`type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/type) attribute is left undefined, and when attempting to create an image with –

```
src = URL.createObjectURL(file)
```

the image fails to load and throws an error, presumably because the file is not recognized as an image.

Is there any way to work around this, or are HDR images not supported by file inputs and the `File` interface? This only needs to work in Chrome, but ideally is cross-browser.

Comment: Browsers can only display image formats they know how to decode. `.hdr` is not one of those formats.

Comment: Yeah I kinda forgot in my abstractions I need to pass the src to the HDR loader in Three.js, not just an image.

Answer (score 0):

This works when passing the `src` to the Three.js `RGBELoader`